# Unable to apply CSS styles to button created by jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I created my button as

```
   <a href = "#" data-role = "button" data-theme = "a" id = "button_style" onClick = "check()">
```

and I tried to apply styles to it as

```
.button_style{
     ---
 }
```

Both CSS and jQueryMobile effects are not applicable to the button. If I include both CSS styles and jQueryMobile styles then jQueryMobile effects like data-theme etc.,  are not applicable to button. But I need both CSS styles and jQueryMobile styles to HTML tag elements. How can I achieve both the things for the button?

Comment: There is no class on the button. I can see only ID so you will need use like this `#button_style`

Comment: you define ID in anchor tag & give style in class.

Comment: I write #button_style, still problem is not solved..

Answer (score 0):

you use .button_style.. this indicates button_style is a class. but you have a button that id is button_style.. so you should use

```
#button_style{
 ---
```

}

check this link // Edited

http://jsfiddle.net/fLq3C/45/

Comment: #button_style{    width : 40px  !important;
    height : 40px !important;
    
    
    background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(63,67,75)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(40,42,47))
 ) ;                                                      background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(63,67,75) 0%,
    rgb(40,42,47) 100%
 ) !important;
 padding: -3px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 9px !important;
}

}

Comment: css is appleid .. Check it my answer.

Comment: CSS is applied but jQueryMobile style data-theme, data-inline are not applied

Comment: put data-inline="true" attribute

Comment: hey friend actually what u want?

Comment: I want button with some styles and data-theme

Comment: Thank u somuch, it works fine when i check it in jFiddle, but when coming to my application, it doesn't work.

Comment: hey friend now i checked in my application , its works fine... can you post more code here?

Answer (score 0):

Because instead of using Id (#) .You used the class notation (.) .Hence it is not applicable

Use

```
#button_style
{
 ---
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/8fUFN/) with your code. By changing to `#button_style` the style works fine.

Check it. Cheers !!!

Comment: Thank you, but data-theme is not applied for button... CSS styles are applied but jQueryMobile themes are not applied..

Answer (score 0):

well without seeing what exactly you wanted here is my attempt:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8fUFN/1/

I pieced together from other answers and comments:

CSS:

```
.button_style {
    width : 40px !important;
    height : 40px !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(63,67,75)), color-stop(1, rgb(40,42,47)) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(63,67,75) 0%, rgb(40,42,47) 100% ) !important;
    padding: -3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" class="button_style" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="button_style" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c" class="button_style" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="d" class="button_style" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="button_style" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="d" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="e" onClick="check()">Test Button</a>
</div>
```

My thoughts are you could you do this with the Theme Roller?

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Also there are some button options you might try:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html